# Initial CakePHP installation Missing controller error

Tags: php, installation, cakephp-2.4

I installed CakePHP vs 2.4,but not load the css files.
therefore, I configurated app/config/core.php with

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

But now I have this error(cake is the project's name):

> Missing Controller
>   CakeController could not be found
>   Create the class CakeController below in file: app\Controller\CakeController.php

Comment: have you enabled `mod_rewrite` in `apache` conf file.?

Comment: Yes, I edit "AllowOverride all" from httpd.conf, but doesn't work, the weird is that asking me for the controller of the project? I work with wamp and my directory is in http://localhost:8080/cake

Comment: I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do, first like Dipesh say, I configurated my mod_write in apache conf file, I missing this: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and allow in directory, config the htaccess docs and I commented this again Configure::write('App.baseUrl', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);